# ACS browse throws: Unsupported orchestrator type Kubernetes for browse

Tags: azure-container-service

Unsupported orchestrator type Kubernetes for browse is the error i get when trying to browse a newly created ACS kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 0):

so the problem as usual was user error. the correct command is az acs kubernetes browse